# BibLaTeX: Set number of authors to be shown

Tags: biblatex, biber

It seems like the number of authors which are shown in BibLaTeX before the rests gets pruned by "et al." is "random". Is there some way to set that to a value n? My supervisor wants to explicitly see the first 5 authors.

My style is the following:

```
\usepackage[german]{babel}

\usepackage[backend=biber,
style=alphabetic,
natbib=true,
hyperref=true,
sorting=anyt
]{biblatex}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `maxcitenames` and `mincitenames`:

```
\usepackage[german]{babel}

\usepackage[backend=biber,
style=alphabetic,
natbib=true,
hyperref=true,
sorting=anyt,
maxcitenames=5,
mincitenames=5,
]{biblatex}
```

Comment: But isn't that just an upper boundary? It still prunes away after 1 or 2 authors for some entries

Comment: I just tried minnames as well. Works. Thank you :)